# Can't connect react-native to laravel , only ngrok works

Tags: php, laravel, react-native

I'm testing my react-native app, I use laravel as backend, with a simple **php artisan serve**, in my window laptop and my mobile device plugged via usb.

I tried using:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

and also using my ip with 8000 port (got it using ipconfig)

```
192.168.X.XX:8000
```

Still doesn't work, the only thing that works is using ngrok like this:

```
ngrok http 8000
```

Comment: what do you mean not work? is there any error message?

Comment: no error, my axios api calls are just going nowhere, ngrok works fine but I'd rather jsut use laravel own php server (xamp)

Comment: It's possible that the firewall on your machine is preventing the connection to physical devices while the emulator is working fine.

Comment: Donde you Know How to fix in Windows 10?

Comment: when you access `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, what does it do? Does it run/execute something in the `controller@method`? When react-native access `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, does it also run/execute something in the `controller@method`? What is the expected result when react-native accesses the `http://127.0.0.1:8000`? It would help if you post more info than just us guessing what you want.